# How to install MinGW 64 bits on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I hit this problem: [mingw-w64 installer "the file has been downloaded incorrectly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455927/mingw-w64-installer-the-file-has-been-downloaded-incorrectly) when I download mingw64 from sourceforge. I followed the answer there, downloading https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/mingw-w64-v7.0.0.zip/download. But this file has no binaries that can be executed. I don't know what it does. It looks like a project to be compiled.

How can I simply install MinGW 64 bits in Windows?

Comment: https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: @NikosC. I cannot use msys2 for this specific case as it conflicts with sw.exe

Comment: On sourceforge pages there is a blue box with an 'antennae' like symbol facing up and to right.  That is an RSS feed, which you click to activate.  Windows seems to handle it well.  I think you should start there.  i.e. google how use RSS to do <install MinGW...> .    At least some attempts I made first downloaded an installer, which I ran to get the rest of the files (without much luck ... seemed to only get 32bit tools, not the 64 bit).  I have changed directions & plan to download Linux from the windows app store. ... but I think that compiler won't gen 'apps' for Win 10.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's not a programming issue.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Apparently, installation of tools for programming is considered on-topic. Although "how to download a file" is perhaps not

Answer (score 3):

mingw-w64 is an open source project and the developers provide source code only. If you're looking for Windows binaries then you need to download them from a third party who builds the source.

There are a few configurable options when building the source (such as threading backend and exception-handling backend) so you will see some differences amongst these builds. Here are some options:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2  -- this is the easiest way for installation with ongoing upgradability and support packages. Note that once it is installed you do not need to invoke msys2 to use the compiler , it is possible to just use msys2 for the package manager.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335424/how-to-use-mingw-64-with-qt-creator
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972968/how-can-use-mingw-w64-and-msys2-with-any-ide-like-eclipse-or-codeblocks
- [Official site](http://mingw-w64.org/downloads)  . If you go here and follow the "mingw64-builds" link then here are some more relevant posts:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947302/meaning-of-options-in-mingw-w64-installer
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210917/how-to-install-minwg64-non-of-the-approaches-work
- [nuwen](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html). This is actually mingw-w64 although the guy calls it "mingw" .
- [TDM-GCC](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/)
- [Equation](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran) - includes OpenMP

Comment: There is a MingW Builds Sourceforce page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/  with binaries

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I covered that as "Official site"